# Counting overhead due to packing in C (gcc/g++)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, alignment, packing

I'd like to count/sum up the overhead in an object file due to packing (and, ideally, have gcc minimize it for me).

For example, consider the following structure (32 bit x86, gcc):

```
struct a { 
    uint8_t a_char;
    uint32_t an_integer
    uint8_t another_letter;
};
```

While the actual data only takes up 6 bytes, the structure takes up 12 bytes in memory because both chars are followed by 3 padding bytes. By reordering the structure as follows:

```
struct b { 
    uint32_t an_integer
    uint8_t a_char;
    uint8_t another_letter;
};
```

The structure will only have sizeof(struct b) == 8 (still 4 bytes of overhead).

(1) Ideally, I'd like for gcc to rearrange `struct a` to `struct b` and save me the space, but my version (4.2) doesn't seem to do this for any optimization level.

(2) Alternatively, given `struct a`, I'd like to (automatically) get either the number `6` (total amount of overhead) or `4` (minimal amount of overhead, if members are ordered "ideally"). The purpose of this is to determine whether or not manually reordering structures is worth the time (likely not).

Is there a way for gcc to do (1), and is there a tool that would perform (2)? The closest thing I can think of for (1) is `#pragma pack(1)`, but (I'm guessing) it would have serious performance implications by making most/all memory accesses unaligned. For (2), I'm thinking a Perl script parsing debugging symbols might be able to do this, but I'm not familiar enough with DWARF to know for sure.

Comment: AFAIK unaligned memory accesses are as fast as aligned accesses; it's just that the compiler doesn't perform some optimizations on them.

Comment: Unaligned memory accesses can cause a `SIGBUS` with 4- or 8- byte types - they are important.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Some architectures have zero tolerance for unaligned memory access and will throw a hardware exception when that happens. In that case the operating system intercepts them and emulates unaligned memory access in software, which is much slower than aligned access. Even on "unaligned-access-tolerant" architectures like x86 unaligned accesses are slower and some instructions (e.g. SIMD) have strict alignment requirements.

Comment: @Mehrdad: this is simply not true - on some architectures misaligned accesses are illegal and will generate an exception; on many other architectures there is a performance penalty for misaligned accesses. Since the OP doesn't even mention which architecture he is targeting it's a very bad idea to make such an erroneous blanket assertion.

Comment: @Paul: In silico, @Paul, @trojanfoe: I was talking about x86, sorry I didn't make that clear. I don't know much about other architectures, but AFAIK x86 instructions like `movaps` and `movups` have the same performance, it's just that the compiler optimizes the aligned ones better.

Comment: Sorry. Platform is x86; don't particularly care about SIMD. I thought I remembered that x86 unaligned accesses had lower performance, but this could be either incorrect or out-of-date.

Comment: @Mehrdad: even for x86 it depends on which generation of CPUs you are talking about as there are plenty of cases where you will get a performance hit for misaligned accesses. There are also more subtle performance implications with badly aligned data e.g. crossing cache line boundaries, crossing VM page boundaries, crossing DRAM page boundaries.

Comment: @Paul: I'm talking about the more recent editions (recent Xeons, Cores, etc.). And yeah, crossing boundaries is definitely an issue but not so often with a small struct obviously.

Comment: @Mehrdad, on x86 there *is* a performance difference for aligned vs. unaligned despite being the same instruction (how appreciable that is depends on your code). The CPU simply has more work to do -- especially if you are crossing a cache-line boundary. More so certain guarantees about atomicity only apply to aligned values.

Comment: Really, how hard is it? A naive solution is to just write all your structures with their elements sorted in decreasing size... You don't really need tools to do this for you.

Comment: OK, maybe you don't *need* tools, and perhaps it's not hard in the sense that it takes particular skill, but doing it by hand becomes a little tedious (not to mention expensive!) when you a few million of lines of code and thousands of structures to look through...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For #1, the reason it's not done is that both the C and C++ standards prohibit structure member reordering.

Yes, struct packing will generally reduce performance. And, as mentioned in a comment, in some cases on non-x86 architectures you can get a SIGBUS if you try to operate on a member.

For #2, yes a perl script might be able to do it. Instead of parsing DWARF info, you could try scanning the source code for struct definitions, and maybe generate some small test programs to check the sizeof() of structs and members and so on.

Comment: 1 - you're right, I found it. "Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared." - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf  . Sigh. Thanks.

Comment: It could be added that even if it could reorder it might not help, since it must each member must still satisfy alignment requirements when placed in an array, and various orders on the stack.

Comment: One further performance issue to consider is that re-ordering the struct elements may in some cases result in a less favourable cache/memory access pattern and so worse performance, even though less memory is being used in total.

Answer (score 3):

In linux there is a tool called pahole that will parse an ELF file with debug information and printout for each struct what each of the member's alignment is and how much padding is done by the compiler. You can use that information to guide you into manually packing if you notice that there is too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot always be done the problem is that access to unaligned memory isn't allowed on all architectures. This also simplifies some code for the compiler allowing to optimize certain accesses on the memory itself. Also reorganizing structures is probably not worth your time as 4-8 bytes of overhead per structure isn't a large deal unless you're running VERY memory sensitive software. As for your question I'm not sure if there is a way but I'm sure if someone knows they will let you know (maybe gcc-4.6 with highest optimization flag does it?)